# $\mathrm{Ext}$ and direct limit

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, limits-colimits, derived-functors

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring. Then, for $R$-modules $\{X_i\}_i$ and $Y$, do we always have $$\mathrm{Ext}^n_R(\varinjlim X_i,Y) \cong \varprojlim \mathrm{Ext}^n_R( X_i,Y)$$ for all $n\geq 1$ ?

I would be happy even with a reference.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Rafi The nonsplit ses $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \to 0$ shows that $\operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z}) \ne 0$

Comment: @math54321 Oops, yeah. I guess a correct argument is instead to show that $\text{Ext}^{1}_{\mathbb{Z}}\left(\mathbb{Q},\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}\right)\neq 0$ by looking at the non-split short exact sequence corresponding to an(y choice of) epimorphism $\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}\to 0$. (And again remarking that $\mathbb{Q}$ is nevertheless a filtered colimit of $\mathbb{Z}$s...)

Comment: There’s something I don’t understand: if you’re not restricting to filtered diagrams, you’re asking whether for all $Y$ and all $n \geq 1$, $\mathrm{Ext}^n_R(-,Y)$, is left-exact (since a cokernel is a direct limit), no? Wouldn’t that imply that the category of $R$-modules is semisimple?